# MYSQL performance for multiple row write vs a single row with more columns

Tags: mysql

Is it better for **write performance** to write a row with multiple columns?

`id1 | field1Name | field1Value | field2Name | field2Value | field3Name | field3Value`

or multiple rows with less columns

```
id1 | field1Name | field1Value
id1 | field2Name | field2Value
id1 | field3Name | field3Value
```

In terms of query requirements, we can achieve what we wanted with both structures. I am wondering how write performance would be impacted between these 2 approaches.

Comment: I woud say multiple rows with less columns is better as relational databases are optimized for a certain number of rows and lots of columns.

Comment: The second form also makes it easier to add new names, you don't have to modify the schema. And it makes writing queries easier. Worry about the best design first, not performance.

Comment: I think that the performance difference is below measurement accuracy. But from the normalization point of view the second option is preferable.

Comment: I'm confused by the first comment, and the 'also' in the second comment. Option 2 is the only viable option here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in a complex way by the type of the columns and the binary size of their actual values. For example, if the column is of type TEXT and you write 50Kb of plain text - it will not fit into a single `page` and MySQL will have to use several data-pages to fit the data. Obviously more pages means more I/O.

On the other hand, if you write multiple rows (one value per row) you will have 2 headaches:

1. MySQL will have to update the primary index multiple times - again suboptimal I/O
2. If you want to SELECT several values - you will have to JOIN multiple rows which is very inconvenient (and you will soon realize it)

If you desperately need the **best write performance** - you should consider using [columnar-based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_columnar_storage_disk_mem_mgmnt.html) database. Otherwise stick with the multi-columns option.